Read large binary file in chunks in Microsoft SQL Server
Is there any functionality that allows reading binary file in chunks?
Currenty I am using the following query to read binary files:
SELECT
  image_data.BulkColumn
FROM
  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\bigfile', SINGLE_BLOB) as image_data

When size of the file is about 3 GB, the query takes about 50 seconds to execute.
When I am trying to extract a chunk from varbinary:
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(image_data.BulkColumn, 1, 15)
FROM
  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\bigfile', SINGLE_BLOB) as image_data

it takes about 28 seconds, no matter what the value of substring-offset is.
Are there any other ways to make the file-to-sql gateway in a more effective way? I don't want to store large binary data in the database.

I don't believe so (but not 100% confident, so just a comment). I think you'll need to pre-chunk it before giving it to SQL Server.

Do not forget that SELECT is also sending the data to your application, if you only ask for the first 15 characters of each row then that dataset will be significantly smaller to display.

Well you could just use another language that supports seeking a file (such as Pyhton or C# or Powershell) then push the data into SQL Server. Using SQL for file access is anyway an anti-pattern, it's not a generalized scripting/imperative language

I agree, it is an anti-pattern, especially when MSSQL forces me to grant a permission to execute bulk operations (I want it to be executable only from a stored procedure, but not directly). Do I need to bloat the database?

You can probably use SP_OA stuff to read files, but by then, you'll be misusing tsql (and i probably get downvoted to oblivion). For file + sql i really like FILESTREAM + FileTables, it's pretty easy to setup and you can use files as if they were in a table
